# Jquery - Trying to figure out how to find a certain class then name -- and then do something with them

Tags: jquery, selector

I'm trying to figure out how to find a certain class name within a div AS WELL as a certain name, in the same div. I'm having trouble finding anything besides parent/child, or maybe I'm off-base.  What I'd like to do is pick out each of these and then add up how many there are with this, total.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var items = $(".<CLASS-NAME>[name='<ELEMENT-NAME>']", "#idOfDiv");
alert(items.length);
```

e.g:

```
var items = $(".someclass[name='somename']", "#interestedDiv"); //If the div should be identified by different selectors replace #interesedDiv with other selector.
alert(items.length);
```

Comment: This is great if the OP is actually asking about names. I'm not sure they understand terms exactly.

Comment: Yup, the attribute's name is, well, name.  Thanks guys.